# MySQL sort by 4 fields date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table where there are 2 date columns and 2 time columns (arrival date, arrival time, departure date, departure time)

I want to combine the 2 date fields in one and then sort by date, arrival time, departure time.

So what I want to achieve is display the arrivals and departures of the following x days in order.

From This:

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+--+
| arrival date | arrival time | departure date | departure time |  |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+--+
| 20-06-21     | 06:00        | NULL           | NULL           |  |
| 19-06-21     | 08:00        | 24-06-21       | 08:00          |  |
| NULL         | NULL         | 20-06-21       | 08:00          |  |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+--+
```

To this:

```
+----------+--------------+----------------+
| date     | arrival time | departure time |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 19-06-21 | 08:00        | NULL           |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 20-06-21 | 06:00        | NULL           |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 20-06-21 | NULL         | 08:00          |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 24-06-21 | NULL         | 08:00          |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
```

This is my query right now:

```
SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`arrivalDate`, '%d-%m-%y') >= NOW() 
AND STR_TO_DATE(`arrivalDate`, '%d-%m-%y') <= DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +20 DAY))  
OR STR_TO_DATE(`departureDate`, '%d-%m-%y') >= NOW() AND STR_TO_DATE(`departureDate`, '%d-%m-%y') <= DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +20 DAY))
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`arrivalDate`, '%d-%m-%y') asc, 
STR_TO_DATE(`arrivalTime`, '%h:%i') asc,  
STR_TO_DATE(`departureDate`, '%d-%m-%y') asc,  
STR_TO_DATE(`departureTime`, '%h:%i') asc
```

Comment: `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(...` is cataclysmically poor for performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to split arrival and departure times into two rows (e.g. in your data the 3 rows become 4). Only then you can sort them:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT arrivalDate AS date, arrivalTime, NULL AS departureTime
    FROM t
    WHERE arrivalDate IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT departureDate, NULL, departureTime
    FROM t
    WHERE departureDate IS NOT NULL
) AS sq1
ORDER BY date, COALESCE(arrivalTime, departureTime)
```

In the above example you must replace dates strings with `STR_TO_DATE(...)`.

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=cf49423fc31dc7b7453d442e7bf94b13)

Comment: thank you but I get this error: Unknown column 'arrivalTime' in 'order clause'

Comment: A typo or case mismatch issue.

Comment: It looks ok! but how I can exclude 0000-00-00 dates and NULL or 00:00:00 times? because I get results like these: 0000-00-00, NULL, 00:00:00 OR 2021-06-12, NULL, NULL

Comment: Exclude them by changing the WHERE clause e.g. `WHERE departureDate <> '0000-00-00' AND departureTime IS NOT NULL`. It would have been best if you store dates as `DATE` and times as `TIME` datatype.